# No such file or directory in Intellij while working with filereader

Tags: java, intellij-idea, file-io

I'm new to IntelliJ. I'm running into problems on running very basic File I/O programs.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NamePlaces {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String nameTxt = args[0];
        String placeTxt = args[1];

        Scanner nameScanner = null;
        Scanner placeScanner = null;
        try{
            FileReader names = new FileReader(nameTxt);
            FileReader places = new FileReader(placeTxt);

            nameScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(names));
            placeScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(places));

            while(nameScanner.hasNext() && placeScanner.hasNext()){

                System.out.format("%s lives in %s \n",nameScanner.next(),placeScanner.next());
        }

    }finally {
        if (nameScanner != null){
            nameScanner.close();
        }
        if (placeScanner != null){
            placeScanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

here's my project structure
[image]

and here's my output

```
   /usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin/java -javaagent:/home/abhishek/intellij/lib/idea_rt.jar=42185:/home/abhishek/intellij/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/abhishek/Documents/code/ideaprojects/files/out/production/files NamePlaces names.txt places.txt
        Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: names.txt (No such file or directory)
            at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
            at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
            at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
            at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
            at NamePlaces.main(NamePlaces.java:12)
        
        Process finished with exit code 1
```

So I've been wrestling with this problem for quite some time now. I do not understand why it won't read the file names.txt when it is available in the src folder as well as the out/production/files folder too. What am I missing. I've tried changing directories, classpath seems right too. I'm out of options here. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do not post pictures of your code.  Edit your question and include your code and the error output as text.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

In Java if you are not using `class.getResource()` it will be looking in the project/surrounding folder. If you compiled the `.class` file by hand it would work in its current state. But to fix the issue moving `names.txt` and `places.txt` to the `files` project folder will fix it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. However, I do not understand what do you mean by moving names.txt and places.txt to the files folder. They are already there. Is there something else to do here, such as changing some configuration to let the IDE know where my files are?

Comment: In your picture, they are in the src folder. It needs to be in the outer most file which is your project folder "files". I am not talking about the ones in your compiled file.

Comment: It is in the correct position. It just seems as if it is inside the src folder. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run the program. I however could not figure out a simpler way than this.

So I changed my code by adding

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

to the imports.

And inside the main(), I added the following statement to get the path.

```
Path path = Paths.get('path/to/directory/');
```

And then I used this `path` to hard code the path into the call to the `FileReader` such as

```
FileReader names = new FileReader(path.toString()+"/"+namesTxt);
```

This got the program running. I know this is not the optimum or the desired solution but at the moment, I wanted the program to run.

I will update the answer once I learn more about how the IntelliJ works in identifying files because hard coding paths is not a good software design practice.